# how to validate that an input is email using javascript functions?

Tags: html, validation, email

I need to get the details of the user with a form.
One of the textboxes is email.
How to validate that an input is email using JavaScript functions?
I'm new to html to go easy on me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: If you use [`input type="email"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input), the browser will do the validation for you. (Also remember you always need to validate server-side either way.)

Answer (score 0):

```
function isValid(email) {
  var regex = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
  return regex.test(email);
}
```

[Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)